# Getting bash completion error is a directory everytime I open the terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I just switched over to Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) a few days ago after using Windows for the last 13 years and I am loving it so far.

Of course I started messing around with everything, because that's how I usually learn something new and now I ran into a problem.

I installed Alacritty terminal and everything went smoothly but for one small problem.

I followed those instructions in order to install the bash completions:

```html
mkdir -p ~/.bash_completion
cp extra/completions/alacritty.bash ~/.bash_completion/alacritty
echo "source ~/.bash_completion/alacritty" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now everytime I open the terminal I get the following error:
*bash: .: /home/myname/.bash_completion: is a directory*
I thought I was referencing the folder and not the file, so I opened the .bashrc file in the nano editor but I find no reference to /home/myname/.bash_completion , just *source ~/.bash_completion/alacritty*
I tried to search for this problem, but I didn't find anyone who had the same problem.
Here is my bashrc file: https://pastebin.pl/view/83ce4d25

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221416/discussion-on-question-by-sirmo-getting-bash-completion-error-is-a-directory-eve).

Comment: I had the same problem then find this and read your comments and solved . Hats off to you all. Take love.

Answer (score 2):

So the issue is the following lines in your `.bashrc`

```sh
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
          . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

I'm not sure why you got that specific error, but the lines here are trying to find the path to the `bash_completion` tool and execute it.

Since the completion works after removing the lines, it is already specified somewhere else.

Comment: always glad to help

Comment: How would you deal with that without removing the lines? Since this is a default behavior, I don't want to change the system but respect how it works and find my own way.

Comment: OK, I figured it out and share my intel in a reply :)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Create `~/.bash_completion.d` directory instead and reference it wherever it's relevant.

Following up as I stumbled upon the exact same scenario and wanted to figure out how to process this properly.

For information, I'm running Linux Mint (Debian based).

In `.bash_profile`, there is this line:

```
[ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && source /etc/bash_completion
```

The sourced file contains:

```
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

So far, we got pretty much the same behavior. It's just not handled the same way.

Now, since this is default, it's better not to touch anything to avoid extra issues. Most Linux distributions assume that `~/.bash_completion` is a file with user-defined completions, not a directory.

And there is this (kind of?) convention for creating directory suffixed with `.d` in their name to make things explicit and prevent conflicts (such as our).

The solution would then to be:

```
mkdir -p ~/.bash_completion.d
mv ~/.bash_completion/* ~/.bash_completion.d
rm ~/.bash_completion
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Once the editor is open, update the path from:

```
source ~/.bash_completion/alacritty
```

to:

```
source ~/.bash_completion.d/alacritty
```

Reload and you should be good to go no matter the distribution you're working on :)